# Over voltage protection circuit ringing

Tags: mosfet, over-voltage-protection, ringing

I am testing the following circuit that is used as an over-voltage protection.
[image: OVP Circuit]

My load is 240ohm  in parallel with 100uF.

When the OVP circuit is not loaded (I disconnect the output of the FET from the load) - it operated as intended - output is disconnect when input increases above 33V.

However when the FET is loaded, I get some kind of ringing on the Gate of the FET, when reaching 33V.
This ringing increases in frequency as I increase the input voltage.

I managed to stop the ringing when I added a 100nF in parallel to R4. However I am concerned that I am missing something here that might come back to bite me later on.

I am looking for some suggestions on what else should I look at, or what may be the cause of the ringing?

Below I added some images of:

1 - FET gate when VIN = 34V

2 - FET Gate when Vin = 35V

3 - Board layout (8 layers, OVP circuit is on bottom layer, layer 7 is full GND plane)

Thanks!
[image: Ringing at 34V]

[image: Ringing at 35V]

[image]

Comment: What power source are you using? Is that fluctuating in sympathy with what you see on the gate?

Comment: Power source is bench power supply - It does not show anything that relates to the issue I am facing

Comment: Try adding a strong decoupling capacitor close to the input power to the MOSFET. It might resolve the issue or begin to indicate where else the issue might lie.

Comment: 10uF capacitor  at the MOSFET input seemed to solve the issue.
Not sure how this makes me feel. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like parasitic oscillation. This can easily occur in mosfets & is usually caused by a larger inductance on the source wire than the drain wire.

The effect acts like an lc tank circuit that oscillates at a specific resonant frequency for that particular mosfet. You can try adding resistance to the gate to attempt to dampen out / prevent the oscillation.

[Here](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/application_note_en_20180726_AKX00066.pdf?did=59456) is an in-depth application note from TOSHIBA on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

When you added the 100nF capacitor, you are changing the turn on/off speed of M1 and decreasing the dv/dt. This could also be done by increasing the gate resistance.

In the schematic I don't see a decoupling cap on VIN. This is very important and helps reduce these types of spikes. Try putting a fairly large ceramic capacitor on VIN to GND. This capacitor should be located as close as possible to the source of M1. I would start out with at least 4.7uF. If it helps, then add more until the spike/ringing is at the desired level.

Another option is an RC snubber across M1. I try to avoid using snubbers due them reducing the efficiency. However, since your circuit is for OVP and isn't constantly switching this is perfectly acceptable and a fix. My goto starting value for snubbers is 1000pF and 10ohm. Then I'll test the circuit and adjust the values as needed.

If you rework the decoupling capacitor or RC Snubber on the PCB. Try and avoid using parts with really long leads. Try using SMT parts if possible. Using through hole components will have more parasitic inductance and may negate the part you reworked into the circuit.

Comment: Adding a 10uF capacitor at the MOSFET input solved the issue.
I prefer this solution and not this snubber. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> What power source are you using? Is that fluctuating in sympathy with
> what you see on the gate? – Andy aka

> *Power source is bench power supply - It does not show anything that
> relates to the issue I am facing – ZelmaB*

> Try adding a strong decoupling capacitor close to the input power to
> the MOSFET. It might resolve the issue or begin to indicate where else
> the issue might lie. –  Andy aka

> *10uF capacitor at the MOSFET input seemed to solve the issue. Not sure
> how this makes me feel. Anyway thanks for your help. –  ZelmaB*

Don't feel bad. It's a common enough issue; the impedance of your power supply and interconnection wires turns the circuit into an oscillator. Adding the capacitor dampens down the problem by creating a low AC impedance at the MOSFET and this is a common solution for typically voltage regulators. Your circuit is similar to voltage regulator so, it shouldn't be surprising that an input decoupling capacitor is needed.